# Devops 2020 and 2022 attach collection TF254078 No attachable database found

Tags: azure-devops

I am working on migrating Devops OnPremises to Azure devops and have been trying to get the devops migrator configured and working. During this time I detached one of my collections to create the dacpac.

The detach went fine, and then when I tried to perform the migration, the migrator tool error "VS403286: The dacpac is from a Azure DevOps Server Configuration database. You must use a detached Azure DevOps Server Collection database"

I tried to attach the collection with the admin console and it could not find any attachable databases. I then used the TfsConfig.exe in the cmd console and it attached the collection fine.

I then detached the collection using the TfsConfig tool and again it detached fine. Created the dacpac and tried to run the migrator and the error was the same "VS403286: The dacpac is from a Azure DevOps Server Configuration database. You must use a detached Azure DevOps Server Collection database"

So thinking that maybe there was an issue with devops 2020, I upgraded to Devops 2022 and get the same issue where the admin console will not list any databases that was detached.

The database extended properties have the TFS_SNAPSHOT_STATE = complete. I do not know what else to look at or try. Any suggestions?

Tried to attach the collection with admin console but will not attach. Tfsconfig.exe works fine.

Comment: Are you *sure* you're exporting a collection database and not a configuration database?

Comment: 100% sure but the database was mark configuration. We’ve upgraded it from TFS days to DevOps. So hard to way it was that way.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue this morning. There were some wrong items in the extended properties. I created a new collection then detached it. Then compared the extended properties where I noticed the difference in the extended properties. List of differences and changes posted below.

```
TFS_DATABASE_TYPE = Configuration
```

Changed to

```
TFS_DATABASE_TYPE = Collection
```

And deleted:

```
TFS_DEPLOYMENT_TYPE = OnPremises
```

After these changes, the admin console can see attachable collections now, and the migrator validated the `*.dacpac`. Seems like it is all good now.